# ob_get_clean with ob_start callback function

Tags: php, buffer

I'm trying to get buffered output with a multiple ob_start. Some ob_start has callback functions. Functions calls but with no effect.

```
<?php
function callback($buffer)
{
    return "deleted\n";
}

ob_start();
echo "first\n";
ob_start("callback");
echo "second\n";
ob_start();
echo "third\n";

$final = '';
$levels = ob_get_level();

for ($i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++) {
    $final .= ob_get_clean();
}
echo $final;
```

Expected result is

```
third
deleted
first
```

But I get

```
third
second
first
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised by it as well, and the documentation could be more clear about this. According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php):

> ob_get_clean() essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and
>   ob_end_clean().

However, the `$callback` of `ob_start($callback)` [is called when](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

> [...] the output buffer is flushed (sent) or cleaned (with ob_flush(),
>   ob_clean() or similar function) or when the output buffer is flushed
>   to the browser at the end of the request.

When `$callback` is called `ob_get_contents()` has already been called and it has no effect on `$contents`.

We can confirm it in [PHP source code:](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/output.c)

```
PHP_FUNCTION(ob_get_clean)
{
    if (zend_parse_parameters_none() == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_THROWS();
    }

    if(!OG(active)) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    if (php_output_get_contents(return_value) == FAILURE) {
        php_error_docref("ref.outcontrol", E_NOTICE, "Failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete");
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    if (SUCCESS != php_output_discard()) {
        php_error_docref("ref.outcontrol", E_NOTICE, "Failed to delete buffer of %s (%d)", ZSTR_VAL(OG(active)->name), OG(active)->level);
    }
}
```

I don't think there's a way around this. You need to be careful with how you use `ob_get_contents()`. If you want to stack multiple output handlers use only `ob_start($callback)`s. It sure would be nice, if there was an option to invoke the `$callback` on `ob_get_contents()` and equivalents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this is not my code. I was just trying to figure out why some projects on WordPress has caching problems. Now I know. But still have no idea how to fix it.